# How to read WebRTC bandwidth stats/metrics

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've made a project with javascript using the new webrtc RtcPeerConnection. I'd like to know how much bandwidth is used by the connection. I've seen there is a WebRTC Statistics API but i can figure out how to just get some kind of number in mbytes or mbits out of it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Source code: 
https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1

Example: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a BandWidth sample
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/